# Troubleshooting Service Broker: initiator database stuck CONVERSING/NOTIFIED

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

We are developing an application that will use service broker to transfer messages from one database to another.  **SourceDB** is used by an existing application from which we are siphoning off some data.  **TargetDB** is used only by this application and processes/distributes the data we need.  We are only using one type of contract and both DBs are on the same server.

We have set up identical message types and contracts on both, and respective initiator and target queue/service.  On both databases:

- `ENABLE_BROKER` is set
- `TRUSTWORTHY` is set
- Have a unique `service_broker_guid`
- Have `sa` as db owner, with all SSB authorization statements are `dbo` or `OWNER`, as appropriate.

However, when we send a message from SourceDB:

```
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @dialogHandle
    FROM SERVICE [//Service/Initiator]
    TO SERVICE N'//Service/Target'
    ON CONTRACT [//Contract/Notification]
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
SEND ON CONVERSATION @dialogHandle
    MESSAGE TYPE [//Message/Notification] (@RequestMsg);
```

...messages do not find their way there.  Further investigation reveals the following:

- The initiator queue is empty
- The target queue is empty (NB: not an issue of needing to `RECEIVE`)
- The transmission queue is empty
- No errors are recorded, either in the SQL Server logs or in our CATCH error handling in the stored procedure that creates the message
- The initiator queue's entry in SourceDB's `sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors` is set to NOTIFIED if activation is enabled
- SourceDB's `sys.conversation_endpoints` has a new entry  in `CONVERSING` state
- The target queue's entry in TargetDB's `sys.dm_broker_queue_monitors` remains INACTIVE  if activation is enabled
- TargetDB's `sys.conversation_endpoints` has a new entry  in `CONVERSING` state with the same conversation_id and different conversation_handle from SourceDB's entry

Although the test database is SQL 2005 (application must support 2005), I ran the ssbdiagnose utility from my development machine's 2008 installation to dianose the issue:

`ssbdiagnose -S testserver -d SourceDB CONFIGURATION FROM SERVICE //Service/Initiator TO SERVICE //Service/Target ON CONTRACT //Contract/Notification`

That produced the following:

```
D  29912 dbtestsvr  SourceDB  Service //Service/Target was not found
D  29975 dbtestsvr  SourceDB  User dbo does not have SEND permission on service //Service/Target
```

This is confusing, since `dbo` should not be denied any permission, and `//Service/Target` certainly does exist, albeit in a different database.  But my coworker ran a Profiler trace that showed a command being executed looking for `//Service/Target` on SourceDB. Service broker seems to be getting confused somehow.  Adding an explicit route, in addition to being theoretically unnecessary, does not change the situation.

I ran a nearly-identical set of [tutorial commands](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3918916/Writing-SQL-Server-Service-Broker--Applications--Across-Databases.htm) on our test server and everything worked fine, so it is likely something db-specific.

Our setup was working two days ago, so we're probably looking for some setting that might have gotten changed, but with no luck.

Comment: Are you doing this?: http://rusanu.com/2006/04/06/fire-and-forget-good-for-the-military-but-not-for-service-broker-conversations/

Comment: @RemusRusanu, thanks for the reply. Even making sure we are not running any `END CONVERSATION` statements, this is still happening.

Comment: One thing that sticks out to me: dbo in SourceDB doesn't have send permission on Target service. Who is dbo SourceDB and does that user need/have perms in TargetDB? I'm a bit disappointed that SB is still somewhat of an arcane art and that more hasn't been done to make it easier...

Comment: @BenThul, sa is the db owner on both SourceDB and TargetDB. Definitely feeling the truth of your comment on SSB being relegated to arcana. :)

Comment: My suspicion would be that you have either 1) multiple copies of the `//Service/Target` services (in several DBs) and SSB picks a different one from the one you expect or 2) you have a route for `//Service/Target` which sends the message somewhere unexpected

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions again, @RemusRusanu. I ran a SQL Powershell command to look for unintended targets/routes and it found only the one service I created on TargetDB: `foreach ($database in get-childitem)
{
  foreach ($service in $database.servicebroker.services)
  {
    if ($service.name -eq "//Service/Target")
    { write-host $database.name - $service.name }
  }
  foreach ($route in $database.servicebroker.routes)
  {
    if ($route.name -ne "AutoCreatedLocal")
    { write-host $database.name - $route.name }
  }
}`

Comment: Can you run ssbdiagnose with `RUNTIME`  mode instead of `CONFIGURATION`?

Comment: Remus - I'm a co-worker of Calvin's and am trying to help him out with this as well. Can you give me the correct syntax to use for the ssbdiagnose command? I'm running it and getting 0 errors/0 warnings, but I must be running it incorrectly. Here is my command: ssbdiagnose -S MyServer -d SourceDB RUNTIME -SHOWEVENTS -TIMEOUT 30

Comment: Thank you Remus Rusanu for your "suspicion" in comment Jul 26 18:04!! I had same issue and that was my problem: duplicate service and/or route and/or bindings in the same Sql Server instance. We've used SSB for years within the same database. Now I have need to send messages between db's within same instance. I followed Stuart Padley's great example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartpa/archive/2005/07/25/443229.aspx, but couldn't figure out why random number of messages reached expected endpoint while others didn't. Turns out I'd accidentally created the dups while running Padley's script!