# New to Service Broker. Getting Error with setting up Initiator and Target Queues/Services on 1 Database

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I created the Queues, Services, contract, etc.  I'm using the AutoCreateLocal Binding. All this on a database I create to start with.  I have an Activation sp that is fired.

When I run the ssbdiagnose utility as follows

```
ssbdiagnose -E  -S . -d MyServiceBroker CONFIGURATION FROM SERVICE     //test.com/items/InitiatorService TO SERVICE //test.com/items/TargetService ON CONTRACT     //test.com/items/Contract
```

it gives me 1 error.

```
D  29975 MyServiceBroker User dbo does not have SEND permission on service     //test.com/items/TargetService
1 Errors, 0 Warnings
```

I am explicitly granting send on both services and receive on both queues to public role.

```
GRANT RECEIVE ON dbo.InitiatorQueueItems TO public
GO
GRANT RECEIVE ON dbo.TargetQueueItems TO public
GO
GRANT SEND ON SERVICE::[//test.com/items/InitiatorService] to public
GO
GRANT SEND ON SERVICE::[//test.com/items/TargetService] to public
GO
```

What can I do to get this right?

What happens is when I send a message on the contract it fires the sp and removes the message but I never see the response message back on the target queue.

Comment: This has been [caused previously by having multiple copies of the service in different databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658658/troubleshooting-service-broker-initiator-database-stuck-conversing-notified) - see the comments. Could that be your issue?

Comment: yeah I checked that first off.  Brand new server install.  Only have the one database.  I also ran the code to check if there was more than one across the server and found none.

Comment: This diagnose message doesn't seem to have any bearing on it working.  My problem lied in the Activation Stored Proc I had created that somehow got stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This diagnose message doesn't seem to have any bearing on it working. My problem lied in the Activation Stored Proc I had created that somehow got stuck in an infinite loop.